# getting error when try to run any of android sdk tools in mac like sdkmanager, avdmanager, etc

Tags: java, android

I am having this error when try to run sdkmanager in my mac machine

```
    amira$ /Users/amira/Downloads/tools/bin/sdkmanager ; exit;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I have remove java and install it and still having the same error

Comment: Do you have your JAVA_HOME set and ANDROID_HOME. Although, this shouldn't involve the ANDROID_HOME, that does help speed up the builds a bit from looking for it.

Comment: I have tried to set JAVA_HOME many times , ex : /usr/bin, and also /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin, but non of them work

Comment: so if you do a $JAVA_HOME from terminal or echo it from Windows it doesn't show the path? Also if you do java --version does it show a version

Comment: it does have value for both JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME, but it is removed every time I close my mac machine, is there any way to keep them always ?
also my problem now that the uiautomatorviewer open but can not connect to device although the adb is running and can list my connected devices

Comment: Yes, open terminal and type vi ~/.bash_profile and add them in there as an export so they persist between sessions. Keep in mind, the values set will not show in any open terminals until they are closed and reopened. including Android Studio. EXAMPLE: ADD THIS LINE export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) to your bash profile. Then you do "esc" followed by  ":" then "wq" followed by enter

Comment: Then do the same for your path to your ANDROID_HOME follow above instructions but with a new line for: export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/yourname/Library/Android/sdk  <--assuming that is where you put it of course.

Comment: @Sam will that fix my current problem with uiautomatorviewer  and adb

Comment: It might. The uiautomator might be using Android home and java home environment variables to launch and execute. So if they are missing it might not know the paths for those items. Android Studio build notes tell you that it attempts to use ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME if available. However, if the pathways are specified in the project, I would be surprised if that fixes it, but you never know.